# Let's get critical: Nov 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Personal Finance & Money Stack Exchange](http://money.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://money.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Tax-advantaged retirement savings options for someone with no 401(k) and high income](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/24586/tax-advantaged-retirement-savings-options-for-someone-with-no-401k-and-high-in)

  **Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Does money borrowed from other people in U.S. need to be reported in tax report?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/24789/does-money-borrowed-from-other-people-in-u-s-need-to-be-reported-in-tax-report)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [FHA with 15% down and PMI](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/24561/fha-with-15-down-and-pmi)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Do I need to file taxes jointly with my girlfriend if we live together?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/24491/do-i-need-to-file-taxes-jointly-with-my-girlfriend-if-we-live-together)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Automatically splitting payments between people](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/24603/automatically-splitting-payments-between-people)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Accounting Question - How Capital Investments are Tracked?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/24643/accounting-question-how-capital-investments-are-tracked)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Trading US stocks from India](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/24580/trading-us-stocks-from-india)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What's "wrong" with taking money from your own business?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/24942/whats-wrong-with-taking-money-from-your-own-business)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [How to find SEC filings that are important to stock market](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/24751/how-to-find-sec-filings-that-are-important-to-stock-market)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Which tax year does a bonus fall under?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/24544/which-tax-year-does-a-bonus-fall-under)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)

---